# Supporting multiple orientations on a single view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to do a pretty simple thing: support only horizontal orientation in my app, except for 1 stack of view controllers. For simplicity, lets say I have two UIViewControllers. Lets call them maskLandscapeVC and maskAllVC. Each is separately embedded in its own instance of a custom UINavigationController. Here is the code for the navigation controller.

```
#import "MPTLoginNav.h"

@interface MPTLoginNav ()

@end

@implementation MPTLoginNav

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark
#pragma Interface Orientaiton Methods

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.isMaskAllStack)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

On maskLandscapeVC, this code works fine and only the two horizontal orientations can be used. 
Users can navigate from maskLandscapeVC to maskAllVC. The following code takes care of that

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
self.maskAllVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"maskAllVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.maskAllVC animated:YES];
```

At maskAllVC, the code also works great and all four orientations are supported.

Once on maskAllVC, the user switches to VERTICAL orientation. maskLandscapeVC is a delegate of maskAllVC. While in the vertical orientation on maskAllVC, the user presses some button. The button does a call to the delegate (maskLandscapeVC), based on some conditions, maskLandscapeVC decides to dismiss maskAllVC. It uses the following code

```
[self.maskAllVC.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.maskAllVC.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now back on maskLandscapeVC, the orientation is still vertical and of course my view is completely messed up because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you pop it to go back it doesn't really refresh the whole ViewController like it does the first time. Using viewDidLoad instead of viewWillAppear might be the problem. viewDidLoad is only called once.

Do you do a complete layoutSubview refresh if you set breakpoints? Does it call into supportedInterfaceOrientations at all when you pop? What happens if you move your viewDidLoad code to viewWillAppear?